# Why is my Div transition not resetting on mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have set up a div to move up from outside the bottom of the page when hovered over.  This works fine in firefox "responsive design mode", when i try it on Android (firefox and chrome).  The div transitions up on finger over and fails to return to its original state.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Swipe Gesture - Gallery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
  <style>
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .gallery {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: #3A3;
    }
    
    #backButton {
      position: fixed;
      right: 35%;
      bottom: -30px;
      width: 30%;
      height: ;
      background: hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.2);
      color: white;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
      border: solid hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.5);
      border-right: none;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }
    
    #backButton:hover {
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
  <div id="backButton">Home</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :focus also

```
#backButton:hover, #backButton:focus{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If this still not working try to set cursor: pointer to the button.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works a little better.  I added the focus and then the cursor:pointer to #backButton.  The behavior of the DIV is that when fingered it opens, it closes when area outsided DIV gets a finger.  I really need the div to slide out when finger is removed as the area outside the div will do something else when fingered.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the `:hover` event is actually a `:focus` event. Once you click on, it remains focused until you tap outside if it (on a different element).

Use `:active` instead, if you want to make it work on an android.
but, before that add a media query to your css.

example:

```
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
       #backButton:active{
       bottom: 0;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
       #backButton:hover{
       bottom: 0;
    }
```

*note: requires long click on the div*

hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you :) :active works, allthough the slide out behaviour fires almost instantly regardless of the fact my finger is over it.  I think i can work around the problem with the help that has been provided.  If there is anything that comes to mind to delay or hold the div while fingered i would appreciate it.

Comment: You could achieve that using simple javascript. here's a JS fiddle i made: https://jsfiddle.net/sbwnyy6b/1/  check if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mithu, that is very helpful ontouch is something that I did not find when looking for javascript events.

Comment: Thats where I always look .. Just not hard enough in this case.  Lesson learned. I appreciate you :)